# Task Feedback Screen - Multiple Choice

Tags: buttons, design, modal-view, task-flow

I'm designing a feedback screen for a task management system. I require the user to tell the system if they have completed the task or not:

If they have completed the task the "How did you find the task" component expands out at the bottom of the task and asks the user if they liked it or not.

[image: wireframe-current tasks]

However I've come to a bit of a block as the buttons "I've done this" and "Do this now" take up to much space. Maybe its the wording, I'm not to sure.

Would be great to get any feedback on this, currently I think it looks too squashed. Also I've done this and do this now mean two positive actions, so can't use green for both.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think you can show the user just one or two buttons at the time.
Tasks have two states: not complete and completed.

When the user hasn't completed the task yet only show them the button 'Do this now'. When they press this button change it's state and show the 'I've done this' button. There is no need for showing these buttons at the same time.
When the user presses 'I've done this' show the opinion buttons. (Btw, I don't think 'How did you find this task' is grammatically correct, it should be 'What did you think of the task?')

On an other note: Is the 'Do this now' button even needed? Are you keeping track of who is doing what task currently?

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for your feedback, the problem is we can not track if the task has been done due to the tasks require users to go find things around the internet. Hence why we need to ask the user if they have done the task or not. Then other users of the group validate the task completed.

Comment: If you cannot track if the user has done or is working on the task, what does "Do this now" do?

Comment: So it's a list of tasks a group of people work on. So the 'Do this now' button is there to indicate somebody is working on the task, that it's in progress, so other team members don't work on the same task. If this is not the case, I really don't see the use of the 'Do this now' button. The 'I've done this' button should be enough to inform other team members the task is done.

Answer (score 1):

I find that checkboxes are a good way to show if a task is completed or not. And making them clickable, the user can mark the task completed.

[image]

Comment: Hi Casper thank you for your reply. I firstly started off with this however we are unable to track if the task has been done or not due to user is required to search around the internet as a task for different things (research). So we need to ask the user if the task has been done or not, then others validate this.

Comment: I'm confused by this limitation.  The answer above is the one I would have given, and it seems to me that it would be the same interaction as you described above.

Comment: You should be able to use the checkbox the same way as a button. So when the user clicks the checkbox, then the task is marked as completed, and the "How did you.." folds down. Next time the user visits the list only uncompleted tasks are displayed, so all checkboxes are unchecked. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Hi Casper yes this makes sense. I originally had this   http://s28.postimg.org/pgfv05trh/12_02_2014_07_27_19.png  however the do this now button is required to be present on the window so hence why I went in a different direction.

Comment: Hi, the "do this now" button is actually still present in the image I posted. It is first removed when the user clicks the check box. But maybe I still don't get the process :-) As I see it when the user opens the task list, he has two options for each task, either he marks as completed or he begins to solve the task. If marked as completed he the rates it. But what happens next? Is it removed from the list? And what happens if he press the Do this now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to style completion controls differently, as mentioned before me tasks have state, so your control for task could be a checkbox with 3 states: empty, working on, and complete.

Also regarding like/dislike, it is generally better to group them under "Rate this task" group with icons to like/dislike instead of buttons with alot of text.